# NoClassDefFoundError on com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax package in my OSGi maven plugin

Tags: osgi, pom.xml, noclassdeffounderror, osgi-bundle, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I'm trying to parse WSDL files using the EasyWSDL library on my (atlassian) maven plugin project. I keep getting this error when I try to parse the file and it fails when the project tries to reach the TransformerFactoryImpl class from said "xalan" package. The package is located inside the JDK, so it's supposed to be available to runtime, yet for some reason it can't reach it.

I've tried importing the package through

```
<import-package>com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.*,</import-package>
```

section of the pom.xml, but that gives me the following error:

```
Unresolved requirements: [[my.plugin.package [304](R 304.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax)]
```

Which makes it seem like the other packages of xalan are found, except for the `xsltc.trax` one.

I've tried creating a bundle extension for OSGi that exports this one package and exposes it to the classpath but due to lack of experience and pretty poor documentation on that matter I can't get that working either. Adding Xalan as a dependency and using `<scope>provided</scope>` does nothing as well.

I need to find a way to put this specific package on the classpath when the program is running. When I run unit-tests on my implementations they work just fine, so it seems to purely be a runtime classpath problem.

Is there anyone with experience on this matter? I've little experience with OSGi, and my experience with maven isn't huge either. So I'm hoping it's something I did wrong myself instead of this being an impossible problem to solve.